# Flutter project is not running

Tags: flutter

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':connectivity:extractDebugAnnotations'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':connectivity:detachedConfiguration2'.
   > Could not download kotlin-compiler-30.2.0.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:30.2.0)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/30.2.0/kotlin-compiler-30.2.0.jar'.
         > Tag mismatch!
```

Getting above error.
Flutter SDK version 3.7.5

Answer (score -1):

You have to wait for it. I have waited for about a quarter of an hour, and indeed the application worked without any problems and continued on that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).